# How do I get the start date and end date of the current week?

Tags: vb.net

I have a function that returns the current week of the year where we are now, thanks to one of the answers in this forum. Now I need to get the initial date of that week and the final date of that week.

How can I accomplish this?

```
Protected Friend Function obtenerNumeroSemanas(ByVal dt As DateTime)
    Dim cal As Calendar = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Calendar
    Dim d As DayOfWeek = cal.GetDayOfWeek(dt)
    If (d >= DayOfWeek.Monday) AndAlso (d <= DayOfWeek.Wednesday) Then
        dt = dt.AddDays(3)
    End If
    Return cal.GetWeekOfYear(dt, CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek, DayOfWeek.Monday)
End Function
```

Comment: Using which days as start/end - Sunday/Saturday or something else?  The [`DateTime.DayOfWeek`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.dayofweek(v=vs.110).aspx) property should give you what you need.

Comment: I want something like 19/06/2016 <----> 25/06/2016

Comment: I thought you were after ISO start/end of week... `19/06/2016 <----> 25/06/2016` is standard calendar, not ISO

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Dim dayOfWeek = Cint(DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek)
Dim startOfWeek = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1 * dayOfWeek)
Dim endOfWeek = DateTime.Today.AddDays(7 - dayOfWeek).AddSeconds(-1)
Console.WriteLine(startOfWeek)
Console.WriteLine(endOfWeek)
```

Using today's date (2016-06-19) results in

```
2016-06-19 12:00:00 AM
2016-06-25 11:59:59 PM
```

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Dim dayOfWeek = CInt(DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek)
Dim startOfWeek = DateTime.Today.AddDays(+1 * dayOfWeek).ToShortDateString
Dim endOfWeek = DateTime.Today.AddDays(4 + dayOfWeek).AddSeconds(+1).ToShortDateString
MessageBox.Show(startOfWeek)
MessageBox.Show(endOfWeek)
```

that to get the next monday date and the next friday

Answer (score 0):

Dim result$ = DateTime.Today.AddMonths(-1).ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy")

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).