# ASP.NET MVC data filter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I am trying to show a large amount of data split into different tabbed sections.

I'm looking at

```
@For Each item In (Model.Where(Function(w) w.new_submittedon = Date.Today))
```

in my view to display only records with a `submittedon` date of the current day.

Can I do the same with current week, current month, current year?

Comment: Sure you can.  What have you tried?  There are a ton of questions & answers to demonstrate how to get dates in the past week, month and year.  Please explain what you have found in your research and how your attempts to use those solutions did not give you the result you need.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get the start date and end date of the current week?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37912201/how-do-i-get-the-start-date-and-end-date-of-the-current-week)